# SSH authentication between my VPS and Bitbucket fail

Tags: centos, ssh, authentication, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I'm trying to setup SSH authentication between my VPS and Bitbucket for configure later automatic deployment via Capistrano (for web projects) and Capifony (for Symfony2 projects) so I follow this steps:

1. Login in my VPS as root and execude the command `cd ~` and that point me at `/root` home.
2. Run the command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my_email@example.com"`
3. Then I added the key to ssh-agent by running the command `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
4. Finally I try to test if all goes fine by running `ssh -T "my_email@example.com"@bitbucket.org` but get this error:

> Permission denied (publickey).

What I miss? Any help or advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add the public key to your bitbucket account? It should likely be added as a deploy key, giving it read-only access to your repo(s).

Additionally, all bitbucket URLs are of the form:

```
git@bitbucket.org:<repo_name>
```

I'm not sure where you're getting the idea to try and authenticate with your email address, but that's not going to work.

To test if your key has been added correctly, you'll need to follow the same pattern as the repo URLs use:

```
$ ssh git@bitbucket.org
```

Read up on bitbucket's documentation - they lay all of this out for you.

Comment: So, adding key as "deployment key" wouldn't work? Why? This is my repo URLs: `reynierpm@bitbucket.org/reynierpm/mapyet2.git` how do I test authentication using that URL? The idea comes from [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) maybe I'm trying to use the right configuration in the wrong place

Comment: Nevermind the problem was the URL's I was using I tried now with `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` and get a success message `authenticated via a deploy key. You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.` thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy the public key ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to the destination host. How you do that on bitbucket I don't know.

Comment: I already did that following [this guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+deployment+keys)

Comment: @ReynierPM you should have mentioned that in your question. I just tried following the guide and it worked as expected so you must have made a mistake.

Comment: He messed up the repo URL.

Comment: @EEAA Yup I could see that once I had had a play myself.